getPackages() method in MainApplication.java
I am new to react native and trying to make a build of old app, I am able to make the build but while bundling I am getting this Native module Clipboard tried to override com.facebook.react.modules.vibration.ClipboardModule. Check the getPackages() method in MainApplication.java, it might be that module is being created twice. If this was your intention, set canOverrideExistingModule=true. This error may also be present if the package is present only once in getPackages() but is also programatically added later during build time by autolinking. Try removing the existing entry and rebuild.
here is my MainApplication.java code
package com.zipaworld.app;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import expo.modules.ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher;
import expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapper;

import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
    new ReactNativeHostWrapper(this, new DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
      @Override
      public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
      }

      @Override
      protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
        List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
        // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
        // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
        return packages;
      }

      @Override
      protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
        return "index";
      }

      @Override
      protected boolean isNewArchEnabled() {
        return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
      }

      @Override
      protected Boolean isHermesEnabled() {
        return BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED;
      }
  });

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
      DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load();
    }
    ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onApplicationCreate(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onConfigurationChanged(this, newConfig);
  }
}


I have seen some solutions where in they said to remove duplicate but I dont have any here. How to resolve this?
i have tries this here and also this but none worked.
